# Haskell: Show screwed up?

Tags: api, haskell

The **show** function in Haskell doesn't seem to do what it should:

```
Prelude> let str = "stack\n\noverflow"
Prelude> putStrLn str
stack


overflow
Prelude> show str
"\"Stack\\n\\n\\noverflow\""
Prelude>
```

When I declare functions, I normally put the type signatures as **Show**, which doesn't deal with newlines correctly. I want it to treat `\n` as newlines, not literally `"\n"`. When I change the type to **String**, the functions work fine. But I'd have to implement a seperate function for integers, floats, etc, etc.

For example, I may declare a function:

```
foo :: (Show x) => x -> IO ()
foo x = do
  putStrLn $ show x
```

... and call it this way:

```
foo "stack\n\noverflow"
foo 6
foo [1..]
```

How would I get the function to return what's expected? I.e. which function is similar to `show` but can return strings containing newlines?

Comment: Can you give us a specific use case of this? It would make understanding your intention easier.

Comment: You could just add a check to see if the input is a string, and just print it. Pattern matching is a very useful thing.

Comment: "show" is just like `repr()` in Python and `inspect` in Ruby, if you've used those languages before.

Comment: The comparison to Python's `repr` is very apt, because `show` usually produces output which `read` could then parse and construct the original object from. It's not pretty-printing, it's serialization,

Comment: There are many answers saying they do not understand the use case. Some variation of this comes up when serializing a data structure of mixed types with minimal constraints. Eg, wanting to convert some data structure to an XML file. You need to serialize each concrete value, which means converting to a string in some way. `Show` seems like an obvious constraint as it gives a means for ensuring a `toString` equivalent function can be applied. It's not so much that `show` has the wrong behaviour as there is no commonly / obviously applicable `toString` for assembling Strings into documents.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The contract of the show method in Haskell is that it produce a string that, when evaluated, yields the value that was shown.

```
Prelude> let str = "stack\n\noverflow"
Prelude> putStrLn str
stack

overflow
Prelude> putStrLn (show str)
"stack\n\noverflow"
Prelude>
```

Comment: Just to add to this, the function you described is called "print" which is actually defined just as the above

 print x = putStrLn (show x)

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like you're trying to simulate a ToString method, although some of your terminology is 
a little confusing.

You can simulate it like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances, OverlappingInstances,
             FlexibleInstances, TypeSynonymInstances #-}

class ToString a where
    toString :: a -> String

instance ToString String where
    toString = id

instance Show a => ToString a where
    toString = show
```

However, as shown by the LANGUAGE pragmas, this is not very desirable. To really get a feel for what you're trying to do it would be easier if we had more context...

Answer (score 3):

`show` shows the variable in the way that you entered it.

Seems pretty regular to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure the point in what your trying to do. It would help if you clarified a bit. Show is doing what it is supposed to do. Show simply produces a string containing what it was shown.

Answer (score 1):

Porges' plan works and I think it brings out brings out what `show` is really up to, since the confusing behavior you found in ghci will still turn up if you get the IO function you want. Note that I added an instance for Char to Porges' code, since you would presumably want that not to have quotes.

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances, OverlappingInstances,
         FlexibleInstances, TypeSynonymInstances #-}
class ToString a where
  toString :: a -> String

instance ToString String where
  toString = id

instance ToString Char where
  toString x = [x]

instance Show a => ToString a where
  toString = show

foo :: (ToString a) => a -> IO ()
foo x = do {putStrLn $ toString x}
```

then, in ghci, watch what happens with `foo.show`:

```
*Main> let str =  "stack\n\noverflow"   
*Main> show str   
"\"stack\\n\\noverflow\""    
*Main> putStrLn str   
stack  

overflow  
*Main> putStrLn (show str)  
"stack\n\noverflow"  
*Main> foo str   
stack  

overflow  
*Main> foo (show str)  
"stack\n\noverflow"  
*Main> foo ( show (show str))  
"\"stack\\n\\noverflow\""  
*Main> let newl = "\n"  
*Main> foo newl  


*Main> putStrLn newl  


*Main> putStrLn (show newl)  
"\n"   



*Main> foo (show newl)  
"\n"  
*Main> foo (show (show newl))  
"\"\\n\""  
*Main>
```

Answer (score -1):

"which function is similar to `show` but can return strings containing newlines?"

Answer: `id`

Comment: Are you just trying to be funny or did you just notr ead the question?

Comment: This is pretty old, but perhaps mattiast meant `putStrLn $ id "stack\n\noverflow"` which does answer the question.