# Haskell: Suppress quotes around strings when shown

Tags: haskell

The following [code](http://ideone.com/OAfye):

```
data HelloWorld = HelloWorld; 
instance Show HelloWorld where show _ = "hello world";

hello_world = "hello world"

main = putStr $ show $ (HelloWorld, hello_world)
```

Prints:

```
(hello world,"hello world")
```

I'd like it to print:

```
(hello world,hello world)
```

i.e. I want behaviour like the following:

```
f "hello world" = "hello world"
f HelloWorld = "hello world"
```

Unfortunately, `show` does not satisfy this, as:

```
show "hello world" = "\"hello world\""
```

Is there a function that works like `f` that I've described above?

Comment: It's generally accepted to be good practice to create a new typeclass (e.g. named `PPrint`) for translations to human-readable `String`s.

Comment: @Clinton did any of these answers help?

Comment: `f HelloWorld = "hello world"` requires lexical analysis and case change. Regex might be the ticket.

Answer (score 24):

Firstly, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968198/haskell-show-screwed-up). Maybe you will be satisfied with `toString` function.

Secondly, `show` is a function that maps some value to a `String`.

So, it makes sense that quotes should be escaped:

```
> show "string"
"\"string\""
```

> Is there a function that works like `f` that I've described above?

Seems like you're looking for `id`:

```
> putStrLn $ id "string"
string
> putStrLn $ show "string"
"string"
```

Answer (score 5):

To complete this last answer , you can define the following class :

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}

class PrintString a where
  printString :: a -> String

instance PrintString String where
   printString = id

instance PrintString HelloWorld where
   printString = show

instance (PrintString a, PrintString b) => PrintString (a,b) where
   printString (a,b) = "(" ++ printString a ++ "," ++ printString b ++ ")"
```

and the function f described  will be the printString function

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a standard typeclass that will do this for you, but one workaround would be to define a newtype:

```
newtype PlainString = PlainString String
instance Show PlainString where
  show (PlainString s) = s
```

Then `show (PlainString "hello world") == "hello world"` and you can use `show` as normal with other types.