# Is there a polymorphic `toString` function that doesn't add quotes?

Tags: string, haskell, polymorphism

In most OO languages that I'm familiar with, the `toString` method of a `String` is actually just the identity function. But in Haskell `show` adds double quotes.

So if I write a function something like this

```
f :: Show a => [a] -> String
f = concat . map show
```

it works as expected for numbers

```
f [0,1,2,3]  -- "0123"
```

but Strings end up with extra quotes

```
f ["one", "two", "three"] -- "\"one\"\"two\"\"three\""
```

when I really want `"onetwothree"`.

If I wanted to write `f` polymorphically, is there a way to do it with only a `Show` constraint, and without overriding the Show instance for String (if that's even possible).

The best I can come up with is to create my own type class:

```
class (Show a) => ToString a where
   toString = show
```

and add an instance for everything?

```
instance ToString String where toString = id
instance ToString Char where toString = pure
instance ToString Int
instance ToString Maybe
...etc
```

Comment: I ended up using the `newtype` construct to create a [`LiteralString`](https://github.com/corsis/PortFusion/blob/ad63a006cff324667cca2316699e26a0078fbc02/src/Main.hs#L67) type with custom `Show` and `Read` instances: https://github.com/corsis/PortFusion/blob/ad63a006cff324667cca2316699e26a0078fbc02/src/Main.hs#L67

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102874/haskell-suppress-quotes-around-strings-when-shown

Comment: Note that `Show` not only adds double quotes. It also escapes characters such as line breaks. For example, the one-character string `"\n"` is shown as a four-character string, with characters ", \, n, ".

Comment: True. But this is also mostly not what you want if you (for example) `print` a value, unless it's a complex type.

Comment: @PeterHall if you are printing to streams in the context of an IO monad, you could use a more specific action such as `putStr`, `putStrLn`, `hPutStr`, `hPutStrLn` - these would not change your strings in any way (no double quotes, newline escapes, etc.)

Comment: @CetinSert But then you couldn't write the function polymorphically. It's the same problem as my original question. If you know it's a String you can use `putStr` - but to be polymorphic you have to use `print` - aka `putStr . show`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Pretty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/wl-pprint/1.1/doc/html/Text-PrettyPrint-Leijen.html#g:10) class and its corresponding type [`Doc`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/wl-pprint/1.1/doc/html/Text-PrettyPrint-Leijen.html#t:Doc) have the needed behavior for Show. Your link shows a different use case, however; maybe you could edit the question?

Answer (score 8):

I think the root cause of your problem is that `show` isn't really `renderToText`. It's supposed to produce text that you could paste into Haskell code to get the same value, or convert back to the same value using `read`.

For that purpose, `show "foo" = "foo"` wouldn't work, because `show "1" = "1"` and `show 1 = "1"`, which loses information.

The operation you want to be able to apply to `"foo"` to get `"foo"` and to `1` to get `"1"` is something other than `show`. `show` just isn't a Java-esque `toString`.

When I've needed this before, I have indeed made my own new type class and made a bunch of things instances of it, and then used that rather than `Show`. Most of the instances were implemented with `show`, but `String` wasn't the only one I wanted to customise so the separate type class wasn't completely wasted. In practice, I found there were only a handful of types that I actually needed the instance for, and it was pretty trivial to add them as I got compile errors.

Comment: Ben, your answer is not accurate. The purpose of `Show` is to render a Haskell value to a string. There is no obligation to have isomorphic Read/Show instances - see the Haskell Report. Admittedly isomorphic Read/Show instances are useful, but they are not obligatory. If you want serialization consider using `Binary` instead.

Comment: Well that's true, but given the standard library instances (and the ones produced by `deriving`) all use Haskell syntax, it's pretty clear that the intended audience for `show`-produced strings is Haskell programmers. It's not intended for "format this value text so I can display it to users".

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}

class Show a => ToString a where 
    toString :: a -> String

instance Show a => ToString a where 
    toString = show

instance ToString String where 
    toString = id

Prelude> toString "hello"
"hello"
Prelude> toString 3
"3"
```

Note that this is probably a terrible idea.

Comment: Thanks. I particularly enjoyed your final words "Note that this is probably a terrible idea." :) Can you explain what the different language extensions actually do to enable this?

Comment: Without `FlexibleInstances`, you're not allowed to have bare type variables stand as members of type classes. Without `UndecidableInstances`, at least one of the instance's type arguments must not be a bare type variable. Not having either of these would disallow the first instance declaration above. And without `OverlappingInstances` we couldn't have both of the above instances together, because obviously the first instance applies to all showable types, and `String` is such a type, i.e. they overlap.

Comment: Wrt your comment about it being (probably) a terrible idea, is the issue that the instances could leak into other modules?

Comment: I haven't really thought through how terrible it actually is, I'm just instinctually wary of extensions that introduce undecidability into typechecking :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `newtype` with `OverloadedStrings`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Data.ByteString.Char8      (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

newtype LiteralString = LS ByteString
instance IsString LiteralString where fromString  = LS . B.pack
instance Show     LiteralString where show (LS x) = B.unpack x
instance Read     LiteralString where readsPrec p s = map (\(!s, !r) -> (LS s,r)) $! readsPrec p s

hello :: LiteralString
hello = "hello world"

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn . show $! hello
```

---

output:

```
hello world
```

---

The double quotes in the normal case are actually useful when reading a shown string back in the context of larger expression as they clearly delimit shown string values from values of other shown types:

```
x :: (ByteString, Int)
x =     read . show $!  ("go", 10)
--  string value starts --^^-- ends

y :: (LiteralString, Int)
y =     read . show $!  ("go", 10) 
-- string value starts --^       ^ consumes all characters; read fails
```

Comment: I think the main problem with that is that it still relies on the caller of the function to know they have to use some a non-standard String type.

Comment: I think the main problem with `show` is its strong coupling with `read` no matter what people may say against using them for pretty printing / parsing purposes; default behaviour of `read . show = id` and that seems to be the reason for double quotes.