# Char -> String without quotes

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I have problem with making list of chars , but casted to string.

I tried write function:

```
charSymbol:: Int -> [String]
charSymbol n = map show (take n ['a'..'z'])
```

I wanted to have list like ["a", "b" ,"c" .... "z"] but instead i got [" 'a' ", " 'b' ", .....] (spaces between " ' was added by me, program makes "').

It is possible to cast char to string without quoutes ?

I found 
[Haskell: Suppress quotes around strings when shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102874/haskell-suppress-quotes-around-strings-when-shown)
but it doesn't looks like answer to my problem,

Comment: I'm not a haskell expert, but following the advice from the duplicate you should be able to do `map (\c -> [c]) (take n ['a'..'z'])`

Comment: Youst wrap it in a list, for example with `pure`.