# Why is this Haskell program making backslashes?

Tags: string, haskell, recursion, output

I'm new to Haskell, and wrote this program to practice functional programming. I have no idea if it is a good program, except for two things.

- It works (it shows me the path from 6 to 1 in a Collatz tree)
- It prints way too many backslashes

```hs
next_step :: Integer -> Integer
collatz :: Integer -> String

next_step n = do
        if (n `mod` 2) == 0 then
                n `div` 2
        else
                (n * 3) + 1

collatz 1 = "1"
collatz n = (show n) ++ " -> " ++ (show (collatz (next_step n)))

main = putStrLn (collatz 6)
```

Output:

```
6 -> "3 -> \"10 -> \\\"5 -> \\\\\\\"16 -> \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"8 -> \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"4 -> \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"2 -> \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"1\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\"\""
```

I would like for the backslashes to go away.

Comment: Easy, just enter `fix show` into ghci before running `main` to fix the way `show` works. ;-) (You will need to import `Data.Function`.)

Comment: @DanielWagner Some advanced Haskellers may think this ia a cute joke, but it will just confuse anyone asking this question.

Comment: @amalloy I have more faith in our learny bois than you do. A winky face, and ghci immediately answering with more backslashes than you can shake a stick at, will be enough clue for anybody that it's just for funsies. And if not, now we have two incredibly serious comments telling them, too!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`collatz` already returns a string, so you don't need to call `show` on it:

```
collatz n = show(n) ++ " -> " ++ collatz (next_step n)
```

Using `show` adds quotes, which then causes the backslashes due to nested quotes.

Comment: By the way, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968198/haskell-show-screwed-up/968228#968228 for an explanation of why the quotes are added